# Empty results with Where Clause

Tags: mysql, php

I have problem with showing results from "visits" table depending on search form !

here is the code !

```
                <?php

                $date1 = $_POST['day'] . "-" . $_POST['month'] . "-" . $_POST['year'];
                $date2 = $_POST['day1'] . "-" . $_POST['month1'] . "-" . $_POST['year1'];
                $product=$_POST['product'];
                $region=$_POST['region'];
                $speciality=$_POST['speciality'];
                $type=$_POST['visit_type'];

$query="SELECT id, name, seller_1_name, seller_2_name FROM visits Where (speciality ='$speciality') AND (type ='$type') AND (product ='$product') AND (date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')";
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>

<h3> Showing results where Product is <?php echo $product; ?>, Speciality is <?php echo $speciality ?>, Region is <?php echo $region ?> and Type is <?php echo $type ?>.</h3>
        <table class="auto-style4" style="width: 100%" border="1"><tr>
        <td style="height: 18px">ID</td>
        <td style="height: 18px">Name</td>
        <td style="height: 18px">seller one name</td>
        <td style="height: 18px">seller 2 name</td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {


$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"seller_1_name");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"seller_2_name");

?>        
        <td><?php echo $f1; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $f2; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $f4; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $f5; ?></td>
         </tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

it shows the heading with the correct variables entered but the table is empty with error code :

Warning: mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/ebarea/public_html/.../.../results_submitt.php on line 175

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/ebarea/public_html/.../.../results_submitt.php on line 176

What's WRONG >!

Comment: Add `or die(mysql_error())` behind the `mysql_query()` call to see the actual database error. But my guess is that you need `yyyy-mm-dd` formatting for your date.

Comment: you don't seem to be actually querying the database? where does the $result come from?

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).  You also don't appear to ever be *running* your query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never executed [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  Maybe something along the lines of:

```
$query="SELECT id, name, seller_1_name, seller_2_name FROM visits Where (speciality ='$speciality') AND (type ='$type') AND (product ='$product') AND (date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')";
$result=mysql_query($query); ## This line is new.
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

To fix your date issues, you may need to be explicit in how you tell MySQL about the dates.  For example:

```
$query="SELECT 
            id, name, seller_1_name, seller_2_name
        FROM visits 
        WHERE
            (speciality ='$speciality') AND
            (type ='$type') AND
            (product ='$product') AND
            (date BETWEEN DATE('$date1') AND DATE('$date2'))";
```

As others have pointed out, however, the code you are using to populate your variables is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack, and should really be updated.

Comment: Excellent :) but the date from and to is not working :/ any ideas ?!

Comment: I don't know the layout of your tables, but maybe you need to explicitly tell MySQL that you're using dates instead of just strings?  I'll edit my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

There are no

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

before

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forget to run mysql_query before:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you process multiple rows, idd, don't forget mysql_query(); Also it's wise to parse user input, now you are totally vulnerable to sql-injection.

```
$query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$total = mysql_num_rows();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object() )
{
   $data[] = $row;
}
foreach( $data as $r )
{
  echo "<td>".$r->id."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$r->name."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$r->seller_1_name."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$r->seller_2_name."</td>";
}
```